# How to delete files from harddisk, when deleted on association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm creating a little website to upload pictures to albums. For both I have models. For easier readability I just name the Application `Website`. My problem is, that I want to delete the files from harddisk, when an album is deleted (and also when an user is deleted).

```
defmodule Website.Picture do
  use Website.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Schema

  schema "pictures" do
    field :pic, Website.ImageUploader.Type
    belongs_to :album, Website.Album
  end
...
end

defmodule Website.Album do
  use Website.Web, :model

  schema "albums" do
    has_many :pictures, Website.Album
  end
...
end
```

I managed to delete the files, when a picture is directly deleted, by calling the delete function of the ImageUploader in the picture controller.

```
defmodule Website.PictureController do
  ...
  def delete(...) do
    # get picture and check that current user is the owner
    ...
    # delete image from harddisk
    Website.ImageUploader.delete({picture.pic, picture})
    # then delete from DB
    Repo.delete!(picture)
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there an easy way to delete the files, e.g. in my ImageUploader or maybe from the model? Or is the only way to do it in the controller by iterating over all pictures of the album?

```
defmodule Website.ImageUploader do
  use Arc.Definition

  use Arc.Ecto.Definition

  @version [:original]

  def __storage, do: Arc.Storage.Local
end
```

To clear things up, here are my migrations

for album:

```
create table(:albums) do
  # some fields
end
```

for picture:

```
create table(:pictures) do
  add :pic, :string
  add :album_id, references(:albums, on_delete: :delete_all)
end
```

Comment: Check out `on_delete` here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#references/2 and here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3. I'd recommend adding it to the migration instead of schema.

Comment: @Dogbert I've added my migration. The database entries are deleted correctly. But not the files on the harddisk.